# Validation loss decreasing faster than training loss

Tags: validation, training-error

I have two different scenarios that I ran across and I can't seem to wrap my head around what caused them.

In this scenario, my validation loss, in orange, initially fell faster than my training loss, in blue.

[image: Valid loss initially decreases faster than training loss]

In this scenario, my training loss has all but converged but the validation loss continues to make big improvements.

[image: Valid loss decreases after training loss converges]

The end results look look as expected and the final validation loss is still higher than the training loss. Does anyone have any insight into what might have caused this to happen?

Comment: What do the numbers on x- and y-axis mean?

Answer (score 0):

Because validation data set is different from the training data set, so, ideally anything can happen in validation error over time.

For your first plot, we can see that training loss line is much smoother than validation line, this indicates you have a lot of training samples but relatively small validation sample (which is very normal in most cases). On the other hand, if number of validation samples is small, the validation loss is "less stable" and will have "large variance". This is why you may see sudden drop or increase over time. Let us use an extreme example to derive intuition: suppose there are only two instances in validation set, if the model can make one good classification, then you may see a sudden drop when it happens (when the training algorithm gets the parameters right for that instance).

For your second plot, we can see we got a good performance at training set very fast, but it performs not as good as training on validation set. This is some overfitting on the training set. Adding regularization will help to make the two lines closer but at the cost of both lines will have higher errors.

To conclude, this is may be because the validation set is small and not coming from the "same distribution" of the training set.

Comment: I can see why that might be the case for the first example, but what about the second? I don't see how a small/dissimilar validation set could cause the validation loss to make large improvements once the training loss has practically converged.

Comment: @ayak 2nd case is some sort of overfitting,  i will revise my answer.

Comment: If it is overfitting then how is the validation loss improving? Ultimately, similar performance is reached on both sets. The thing I'm wondering is how the validation loss can improve so much when the training loss has converged.

Comment: I'd agree that over-fitting is not the issue, but it could indeed be that the validation set is too small, so there is a lot of variability in the validation set learning curves.