# why does my model fluctuate on validation set and is smooth on the training set?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, keras

I use the below architecture in keras for dog-vs-cat dataset

```py
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(150,150,3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPool2D((3,3)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPool2D((3,3)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPool2D((3,3)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(512,activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
             loss='binary_crossentropy',
             metrics=['acc'])
```

and got the 85 acc for train and 81 for val_acc
but got the pattern below in validation loss in the end
[image]

but my train validation seems to be normal

[image]

is my model okey and validation loss is okey?
or did i miss something?

Comment: If you could edit your post so as to explain more of your terms and label your axes, this post will have greater benefit, even for those who don't use the keras library.  Cheers ~

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, validation set will have much less data in training set. And that is the reason the performance will "fluctuate on validation set and is smooth on the training set".

Think about an extreme case that validation set only have 2 images, if you correctly classify one, then the performance will suddenly jump to 50%.

I have an answer to similar question here

[Validation loss decreasing faster than training loss](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/462204/validation-loss-decreasing-faster-than-training-loss/462209#462209)